# How to handle a large bitmap without scaling

Tags: android, bitmap

I am working on comic book type of project (user can slide through around 150 pages) where I need to load a large resolution image for each page. But for me scaling down those bitmap not an option because user can zoom in those pages if a scaled down those images its look bad if user zoomed in.

I have also checked my heap size if I reached 35MB limit during execution in some device application crashes.

Please suggest what should I do in such situations.

Comment: You could use image tiles so that not the whole image is in memory when only part of it is shown.

Comment: Use the image viewing intent. Then they can open up your large image, and zoom in with still good quality. (all managed by android)

Answer (score 1):

Configuring your app for **large heap size** will have Android allocate additional 15-30% RAM to your app, depending on device:

```
<application ..............
             android:largeHeap="true"  <---------------
             android:label="string resource"
```

Configuring your image-loading activity to **run within a dedicated process** will 
approximately double the amount of RAM memory available for your app and will
allow you to dedicate most of 'ImageActivityProcess' memory to the image loading logic:

```
 <activity android:name=".ImageActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name" 
              android:process=":ImageActivityProcess"> <----------
    </activity>
```

Still my guess is that all these will delay rather than solve your problem. Mobile devices
are simply not tuned for loading multiple large images. Remember that that on most Android devices there's a **3-4 factor from pixel size to in-memory size** i.e. a 4 MPix image will require either a 12-16 MBytes RAM block.

Think again of your image loading architecture. Consider e.g. loading reduced-size images into scroller and, only when when user clicks on an image or issue a zoom command - load the full scale bitmap. This is what I would do

Comment: +1 nice answer you can explain the horror of running into outofmemoryerror to the op